# Bootstrap accordions on the same page not working if rendered from partial

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

In my rails app, I have a page where up to 3 different partials are rendered depending on a dropdown selection. Every partial contains the same bootstrap accordion, with the ids and data-parent changed to differenciate them. The problem is that if I put them both on the same page, they work as they should [see the code here](https://www.bootply.com/WNDkQKvwGg), but if they are in separate partials, rendered on the same page, the second doesn't work and I have no idea why?

here is the index.html.erb where the partials are rendered:

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="height: 90rem;" >
  <div class="row"><h1 class="page-header" style="color: #777777">Privacy settings<small> <br>Here is a list of the available privacy settings on different social networks. Click on a setting to see its details </small></h1><br>


  </div>

  <div class="row" style="padding-bottom: 3rem;text-align: center"> <!-- selection row -->

    <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1 dropsel"> <!-- first column -->

      <select id="selectMe2" class="selectpicker" data-width="fit" title="Choose social network" >
        <option>None</option>
        <option value="facebook2">Facebook</option>
        <option value="twitter2">Twitter</option>
        <option value="linkedin2">LinkedIn</option>
        <option value="google2">Google +</option>
        <option value="pinterest2">Pinterest</option>
      </select>
    </div>

      <div class="col-md-3 dropsel" > <!-- second column -->

        <select id="selectMe3" class="selectpicker" data-width="fit" title="Choose social network">
          <option>None</option>
          <option value="facebook3">Facebook</option>
          <option value="twitter3">Twitter</option>
          <option value="linkedin3">LinkedIn</option>
          <option value="google3">Google +</option>
          <option value="pinterest3">Pinterest</option>
        </select>

      </div>

        <div class="col-md-3 dropsel" > <!-- third column -->

          <select id="selectMe4" class="selectpicker" data-width="fit" title="Choose social network">
            <option>None</option>
            <option value="facebook4">Facebook</option>
            <option value="twitter4">Twitter</option>
            <option value="linkedin4">LinkedIn</option>
            <option value="google4">Google +</option>
            <option value="pinterest4">Pinterest</option>
          </select>

        </div>
  </div>


<div class="row"> <!-- content row  -->
  <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1 dropcont"> <!-- first content column -->


      <div id="facebook2" class="group2" >
        <%= render partial:"fbpartial2" %>
      </div>

      <div id="twitter2" class="group2" >
        <%= render partial:"twpartial2" %>
      </div>

      <div id="linkedin2" class="group2" >
        <%= render partial:"lkpartial" %>
      </div>

      <div id="google2" class="group2" >
        <%= render partial:"googlepartial" %>
      </div>

      <div id="pinterest2" class="group2" >
        <%= render partial:"pinpartial" %>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /first column -->


  <div class="col-md-3 dropcont"> <!-- second content column -->

      <div id="facebook3" class="group3" >
        <%= render partial:"fbpartial2" %>
      </div>

      <div id="twitter3" class="group3" >
        <%= render partial:"twpartial2" %>
      </div>

      <div id="linkedin3" class="group3" >
        <%= render partial:"lkpartial" %>
      </div>

      <div id="google3" class="group3" >
        <%= render partial:"googlepartial" %>
      </div>

      <div id="pinterest3" class="group3" >
        <%= render partial:"pinpartial" %>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /second column -->

  <div class="col-md-3 dropcont"> <!-- third content column -->

      <div id="facebook4" class="group4" >
        <%= render partial:"fbpartial" %>
      </div>

      <div id="twitter4" class="group4" >
        <%= render partial:"twpartial" %>
      </div>

      <div id="linkedin4" class="group4" >
        <%= render partial:"lkpartial" %>
      </div>

      <div id="google4" class="group4" >
        <%= render partial:"googlepartial" %>
      </div>

      <div id="pinterest4" class="group4" >
        <%= render partial:"pinpartial" %>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /third column -->



  </div>
</div>

<!-- scripts -->

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.group2').hide();//hide
        $('#none').show();//set default class to be shown here, or remove to hide all
                $('#selectMe2').change(function () {//on change do stuff
            $('.group2').hide();//hide all with .group2 class
            $('#'+$(this).val()).show(); //show selected option's respective element
        })
    });</script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.group3').hide();//hide
        $('#none').show();//set default class to be shown here, or remove to hide all
        $('#selectMe3').change(function () {//on change do stuff
            $('.group3').hide();//hide all with .group2 class
            $('#'+$(this).val()).show(); //show selected option's respective element
        })
    });</script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.group4').hide();//hide
        $('#none').show();//set default class to be shown here, or remove to hide all
        $('#selectMe4').change(function () {//on change do stuff
            $('.group4').hide();//hide all with .group2 class
            $('#'+$(this).val()).show(); //show selected option's respective element
        })
    });</script>
```

the first partial (_fbpartial2):

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12" style="text-align: center; overflow-x: hidden;">

      <div class="row" style="padding-bottom: 4rem;">
        <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i> <br>
        <p> Warning, your profile is only 20% private!</p>
      </div>

      <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
              <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
                <i class="fa fa-plus-square-o pull-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                Public Information
              </a>
            </h4>
          </div>

          <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
            <div class="panel-body" style="text-align: center;">
              panel content

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>


        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
              <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
                <i class="fa fa-plus-square-o pull-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                Public Photos
              </a>
            </h4>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
              panel content

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
              <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">
                <i class="fa fa-plus-square-o pull-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                Public Posts
              </a>
            </h4>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
              Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the second (_twpartial2, identical to the first, outside of the changed parameters I said before):

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12" style="text-align: center; overflow-x: hidden;">

      <div class="row" style="padding-bottom: 4rem;">
        <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle fa-4x" aria-hidden="true"></i> <br>
        <p> Warning, your profile is only 20% private!</p>
      </div>

      <div class="panel-group" id="accordion2">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
              <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne2">
                <i class="fa fa-plus-square-o pull-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                Public Information
              </a>
            </h4>
          </div>

          <div id="collapseOne2" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
            <div class="panel-body" style="text-align: center;">

             panel content


            </div>
          </div>
        </div>


        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
              <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseTwo2">
                <i class="fa fa-plus-square-o pull-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                Public Photos
              </a>
            </h4>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseTwo2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">

panel content

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
              <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseThree2">
                <i class="fa fa-plus-square-o pull-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                Public Posts
              </a>
            </h4>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseThree2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
              Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

you can see the javascript for accordion on the bootply example

Comment: Have you tried comparing your actual rendered HTML with what you have in bootply?

Comment: yes I tried and the HTML seems to be the same

Comment: I really don't understand why it doesn't work

Comment: The problem must be somwhere in the index page, because if I erase everything and only render the 2 partials, it works fine. @SergGr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I think I found the problem. It has something to do with the fact that the same partials are rendered 3 times and hidden when the page is loaded. So when I try to open/close the accordion on the second column, it probably reacts on the first.

I solved it by creating 2 duplicates of every partial and naming them differently, so that every column loads a different partial. I'm sure there is a more elegant solution, but being a beginner I'm happy it works :)